# Ansible environment variable or default

Tags: ansible, jinja2

How do I get a value from an environment variable, but use a default if the environment variable is unset?

This is an example that does not work

```
---
- name: a playbook
  hosts: all
  vars:
    build_dir: "{{ lookup('env','BUILD_DIR') | default('builds/1.0.0/LATEST') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ build_dir }}"
```

Running this playbook returns an empty string instead of the default.

```
$ ansible-playbook build.yml

TASK [debug] ********************
ok: [amber] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

However, it works as expected to obtain the environment variable.

```
$ BUILD_DIR=LOL ansible-playbook build.yml

TASK [debug] ****************
ok: [amber] => {
    "msg": "LOL"
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Discovered this that is more concise and easier to read than some other options I have seen

```
"{{ lookup('env','BUILD_DIR') or 'builds/1.0.0/LATEST' }}"
```

Comment: elegant and pythonic

Answer (score 7):

The last parameter to Jinja's `default` template built-in function should be `true`, like this:

```
  vars:
    build_dir: "{{ lookup('env','BUILD_DIR')|d('builds/1.0.0/LATEST', true) }}"
```

Comment: If you are looking for an explanation, I found this nice blog [jinja2 default filter](http://nikhilism.com/post/2016/understanding-ansible-jinja2-default-filter/)

Answer (score 5):

Better not to have too many sources of truth, but I always try to set intelligent defaults in `defaults/main.yml`. I also make frequent use of the `default()` filter, like this:

```
db_url          : "{{ DB_HOST }}:{{ db_port | default(1521) }}:{{ DB_SVC | default(SID|default('')) }}"
```

Then a playbook can always overwrite a role's variable with a lookup that defaults to a literal -

```
vars:
  db_port: "{{ lookup('env','db_port')|default('9999') }}"
```

or with a value dynamically written into a vars_file before the play begins, or into the hosts file or groups file, or on the ansible command-line with `--extra-vars`, etc.

Look at the [variable precedence rules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable), but be careful not to get too complex if it can be avoided. Flexibility is good, but KISS, else "that way lies madness..."

Comment: Note that (apparently in 2.5?) you need the 2nd argument to `default()` set to `true` [if it evaluates to an emptry string](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables).